# Is there a way one can access the game time variables like health bar and other scores from a game running on unreal engine

Tags: artificial-intelligence, game-engine, unreal-engine4, openai-gym, data-collection

My objective requires that I am able to access game time variables like health bar, certain scores etc, when the game is running. I do not want to change this variables, or cheat in the game in anyway, I just need to collect this data and do not want to modify it.

I need to be able to get that information in a python/c++ environment.  I know that cheat engine like software might be able to help me, but since DRM and anti cheat software prevent me from doing just that and therefore it might not be possible anymore, other option I am currently exploring is to screengrab and using opencv and character recognition get the information I need visually, but this seems like unnecessary and extra work that might even not work that well.

I also explored if there is any API from unreal engine (the game is based on unreal engine) that might just allow me to do just this, but had no luck so far. So I ask you one more time, you to suggest me some solutions to this issue.

I think DOTA 2 allows this in some way, since openAI/others use data like this to train their AI's so it should be possible right!? I am just interested in knowing how can this be done.

Comment: "...screengrab and using OpenCV and character recognition..."  Yep, that's how the folks at [DeepMind did it for StarCraft II](https://deepmind.com/blog/article/alphastar-mastering-real-time-strategy-game-starcraft-ii).

Comment: Are you trying to collect the scores for analytics, or to expose an api, or even something else? Since it sounds like you own the game, using open cv and an ai probably isn't correct because of the performance penalty and lack of cross platform support.

Comment: @George For now, its mostly analytics; with OpenCV not just performance I am also worried about not being able to cover all circumstances within the gameplay to get the results reliably all the time. If unreal engine 4 allowed some way to access the information I require, it would have been great.

Comment: This question is way too broad in scope, each game stores this information differently. If you own the engine code  please present a code example.